# Calling fragment activity form main project app to the module project app on kotlin android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-module

I just want to ask how can I get /call / transfer data from main app to module app in android studio **Kotlin**?
I have 2 modules project inside of my main project

example: **main [App]** then **Module [Chatapp]**

I just want to call class or fragment activity on main project to moudule project **chatapp**. I can only call it in my module now, not in my main project app

I've search on Google but nothing found.

Comment: Your chat module should depend on main module if you want to call some code from it  put this in chat **build.gradle**   `implementation project(':YouMainModule')`

Comment: i do this but they have some error

Comment: you can post your error logs, so we can help

Comment: Use an interface in the module as a caller contract when the module is used in main module. Then you can call the contract to call the main module.

Comment: I'll add up to ישו אוהב אותך's comment. I suspect that you risk ending up with circular dependencies. So I would suggest you to implement it as a callback or still something along the lines of the publish subscribe pattern. BTW With a functional programming language callback can be much less verbose, but they do need a lot of comments.